# Tool for IO analysis?

Tags: performance, io, system

Is there a tool for Win/Linux which **shows me all file system hits on a webserver**?

I once saw something like that for OS X with XCode. I want to improve the systems performance and I'm afraid I miss unnecessary "expensive" hits by Apache, MySQL or PHP.

Things I want to prevent:

- Apache scanning folders for .htaccess files
- PHP traversing for all include_path paths

Answer (score 3):

There's **[strace](http://sourceforge.net/projects/strace/)**. Start your apache with

```
$ strace -f -e open,access,stat -w apache2-io.log apache2
```

You can also attach with to a running process with the `-p` option. If you want to see the filesystem hits in real time, skip `-w apache2-io.log`.

Have a look at the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

On a Unix System you can use `lsof` (list open files), but beware, many files are open usually. You may want to filter the list somewhat, i.e. `lsof | grep apache`.